# How do i initialize an array inside of a struct

Tags: solidity, arrays, struct

I have a struct (Activity) where one of the arguments is an array of int. What i want to do is to initialize the struct and set the `routinesID` argument as an array like i did in the `createActivity` function but when i test the code on Remix i get this error:

> The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
> Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.

If you have any suggestions please help me, it would be very useful.

**The Code:**

```
  struct Activity {
        address owner;
        uint start;
        uint end;
        bool status;
        string activity;
        uint id;
        int[] routinesID;
    }
    Activity[] public activities;    


function createActivity(
        uint _start,
        uint _end,
        string memory _activity
    ) public {
        int[] memory ids = new int[](activities.length);
        ids[0] = -1;

        Activity memory newActivity = Activity(
            msg.sender,
            _start,
            _end,
            false,
            _activity,
            activities.length,
            ids
        );

        activities[activities.length] = newActivity;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any declared size of the array.
Instead of

```
activities[activities.length] = newActivity;
```

Do:

```
activities.push(newActivity);
```